# Smooth scrolling native with nextJs

Tags: reactjs, suave

I have the big problem that I want to add a smooth scroll to my website and absolutely no solution works, neither the CSS nor anything I do. This is because I do not have activated the smooth scrolling flag in edge but when activated the scrolls direct anywhere, and also I do not want to depend on a user to activate this flag to see the soft effect. Is there any way to add smooth scrolling without depending on whether it is enabled in the browser?

Try absolutely everything, the property in the css scroll-behiavor:smooth, thousands of libraries and none works without activating the broswe flag ...

Answer (score 0):

Better go with locomotive js. I strongly recommend to use any framework like React or vue js for website and use locomotive-js v5 library which is in beta state. Caution using locomotive-css other than v5 beta will mess up all the CSS you have written so go with Locomotive js v5 beta.